# Does field length matter much in performance

Tags: apex, soql, custom-field, data, admin

Maybe very trivial question but I don't know the answer. When I create a new field , I always think why don't I give the max length for this field? How does 20 is different from giving 100 as length. Is there any performance difference in the database for this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For normal objects, there's no difference in performance. For Custom Settings and Custom Metadata, allocating too much space will affect the number of settings/metadata records you can create, but otherwise don't affect performance. Note that Long Text Area (LTA) fields share a per-object character limit, too, so creating fields longer than necessary will limit how many LTA fields you can create.

Comment: I just made a couple of text fields significantly shorter. It concerned tens of thousands of records and the change was almost instantaneous. Either Salesforce has a superfast database underneath or such a change is merely administrative and has no consequences for created records.

Comment: @SanderdeJong Salesforce is heavily optimized to allow these kinds of changes to take a trivial amount of time even for millions of records. This includes changes like renaming picklist values, resizing fields, adjusting precision.